# Setting aliases for a route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, alias

I have a few identical pages which have different urls. How can I set for a route these aliases?
So far, I only see the following method:

```
Route::get('/alias1', 'HomeController@someAction');
Route::get('/alias1.html', 'HomeController@someAction');
Route::get('/alias1.php', 'HomeController@someAction');
Route::get('/alias4', 'HomeController@someAction');
```

Is there a prettier way to set aliases?

Comment: Your function the same for all the different URLs in controller?

Comment: yes, a function is the same

Comment: You could use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) in a route

Comment: what do you mean by aliases and is it specifically just those 4 possibilities?

Comment: I mean difference urls for the same action. Yes, I needed only these possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could easily constrain the format of the route parameter using a Regular Expression Constraint:

```
Route::get('{alias}', 'HomeController@someAction')
    ->where('alias', 'alias1|alias1.html|alias1.php|alias4');

public function someAction($alias)
{
    ...
}
```

The route will only match if the path is one of your 4 aliases.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Routing - Parameters - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) `where`

Answer (score 0):

Your Route :

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'HomeController@someAction');
```

Your Controller function:

```
function someAction($slug){
    #yourcode
}
```

OR

You can do one more thing if code in the function is same and nothing to do with the "url"

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'HomeController@someAction')->name('YourUniqueRouteName');
```

work as alias.

Here are some reference Links for more understanding.

[Routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

[Routing#named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) ( For Route Naming )

Comment: 'as' is out since 5.3, it's in 2016

Answer (score -1):

You can use Named Routes

```
Route::get('/{slug}', HomeController@someAction)->name('uniqueNameForRoute');
```

[have a look at Laravel naming routes documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)